# Trouble using gdata and Unicode Cyrillic in Python

Tags: python, unicode, youtube, gdata

I have this code

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
__author__ = 'user'
import gdata.youtube.service
yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
query = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeVideoQuery()
query.vq = u"не"
feed = yt_service.YouTubeQuery(query)

for yt_item in feed.entry:
    print yt_item.GetSwfUrl()
```

And I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "cyr_search.py", line 7, in  
>           feed = yt_service.YouTubeQuery(query) 
>         File "/Users/user/Documents/GrabaHeroku/graba_h_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/youtube/service.py", line 1346, in YouTubeQuery 
>           result = self.Query(query.ToUri()) 
>         File "/Users/user/Documents/GrabaHeroku/graba_h_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1715, in ToUri 
>           return atom.service.BuildUri(q_feed, self)
>         File "/Users/user/Documents/GrabaHeroku/graba_h_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/service.py", line 584, in BuildUri 
>           parameter_list = DictionaryToParamList(url_params, escape_params) 
>         File "/Users/user/Documents/GrabaHeroku/graba_h_ve/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/service.py", line 551, in DictionaryToParamList 
>           for param, value in (url_parameters or {}).items()] 
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1275, in quote_plus 
>           return quote(s, safe) 
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1268, in quote 
>           return ''.join(map(quoter, s)) 
>       KeyError: u'\u043d'

How do I search for non-ASCII. Do I need to url encode the query? I thought the library will do that on its own.

Comment: It looks like the unicode data is directly passed to the `urllib.quote` function, so you probably have to encode Unicode data yourself before passing it to the query. Try using `query.vq = u"не".encode('utf8')` and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
query.vq = u"не".encode('utf8')
```

The string needs to be encoded before being sent.